# Stored procedure - searching not just one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I use this as a stored procedure?

Like what I'm doing at the "where"

- textbox for searching
- comboBox for selecting what column it is on the table

Code:

```
 Create procedure sp_Search
    @Searchthis Varchar(50),
    @Searchwhat Varchar(50)
 as
    Select * 
    from tbl_person
    where @Searchwhat = @Searchthis
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: what do you mean by product specific?

Comment: he means what database engine, sql server, oracle, etc.

Comment: This way won't work...you have to built a dynamic query

Comment: im using sql server

Comment: how can i make a dynamic query?

Comment: google "sqlserver dynamic query"

Comment: @GroverReyes take a look at my answer

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I would suggest that your approach to searching needs to be updated. Instead of allowing any column to be searched you should have a parameter for each column that can be searched. This will mitigate the sql injection issues and give you some performance boost. Check out this article for a much better way to write a search procedure. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not directly concatenate strings to sql and execute them. That is how you leave yourself open to sql injection.

```
create procedure dbo.usp_Search
  @SearchCol varchar(50),
  @SearchValue varchar(50)
as
begin
  set xact_abort, nocount on;
  declare @sql nvarchar(512);
  /* make sure the column specified exists in the table 
    to prevent sql injection :P */
  select @sql ='select * from tbl_person where '+quotename(column_name)+' = @SearchValue;'
  from information_schema.columns c
  where c.Table_Name = 'tbl_person'
    and column_name = @SearchCol

  exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@SearchValue varchar(50)', @SearchValue;
end;
go
```

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

  rextester: http://rextester.com/DOGCZ19676

Comment: @SqlZim On my Original Procedure it would create a "result"

for example sp_SearchResult and I need to use this so I can have something to display on my DataGridView.

Code Sample:

List<sp_SearchResult> search = db.sp_Search(searchwhat, searchthis).ToList();

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create procedure sp_Search
    @Searchthis Varchar(50),
    @Searchwhat Varchar(50)
as
    declare @sql varchar(500)

    set @sql = 'select * from tbl_person where ' + @Searchwhat + ' = ''' + @Searchthis + ''''
    exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sql example:

```
Declare @Sql varchar(800) = 'Select * from tbl_person ' +
    'where ' + @Searchwhat + '=' + '''' + @Searchthis + ''''
```

'''' is escaping the ' around the varchar searchthis

It ends up looking like

```
Select * from tbl_person
    where Name = 'Joe'
```

Then you can call Exec(@Sql)

Comment: While you are wise to note the concern of Sql Injection, not everyone is creating dynamic sql that accepts user input.  I have written dozens of dynamic sql procs and never had to worry about it.

Comment: Joe this is a search. I have never seen a search that doesn't accept user input, it would kind of defeat the purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

So first thing, don't start your procedure with `sp_` that is reserved for system procedures.  You can technically use it, but sql server will have additional overhead looking for it in the system procedures and then execute your query.

You are asking to make a dynamic query based on the selected column.

```
Create procedure Search
    @Searchthis Varchar(50),
    @Searchwhat Varchar(50)
as

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(400)

SET @sql = 'Select * from tbl_person WHERE ' 
   + @Searchwhat + ' = ' +  '''' + @Searchthis + ''''


exec (@sql)
```

Personally, I'm not a big fan of this approach.  To do this, you have to grant read access to the table for the user executing it.  Using stored procedures is meant to make this unnecessary (security), and you lose some type checking (etc.) when you create procedure on the server, because it can't check the query until it executes.  It will work, but I would rather create more procedures to do the searches than use one generic one.  With this approach, you might as well use dynamic sql and remove the extra development overhead of using a stored procedure at all.

Comment: Did you intend to use [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) ? Otherwise you'll need to call [`sp_prepare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848808.aspx) first, get the handle, and use that for [`sp_execute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848746.aspx).

Comment: `exec dbo.sp_Search '', '1=1; [injected sql] --'`

Answer (score 0):

You could achive what you want by having a subquery doing the search on your chosen field via a case statement and then joining again to the table in question.

EG - Just 2 fields shown but you get the picture....

```
CREATE Table #MyTable(
  id int identity,
  Type Varchar(20),
  Description Varchar(20)
  );

INSERT INTO #MyTable
  SELECT 'Type_A', 'Description A'
  UNION
  SELECT 'Type_B', 'Description B'

--Search by Type
DECLARE @SearchField Varchar(20) = 'Type';
DECLARE @SearchVal Varchar(20) = 'Type_B';
SELECT F.* FROM 
(
SELECT #MyTable.Id,
  CASE 
    WHEN @SearchField = 'Type' THEN Type
    WHEN @SearchField = 'Description' THEN Description
  END as SearchField
FROM #MyTable
)Search_Q
INNER JOIN #MyTable F ON F.Id = Search_Q.Id
WHERE
  SearchField = @SearchVal;

--Search by Description
SET @SearchField = 'Description';
SET @SearchVal = 'Description A';
SELECT F.* FROM 
(
SELECT #MyTable.Id,
  CASE 
    WHEN @SearchField = 'Type' THEN Type
    WHEN @SearchField = 'Description' THEN Description
  END as SearchField
FROM #MyTable
)Search_Q
INNER JOIN #MyTable F ON F.Id = Search_Q.Id
WHERE
  SearchField = @SearchVal;

DROP TABLE #MyTable;
```